# Insert into clickhouse JSONEachRow nested

Tags: arrays, json, nested, clickhouse

I have the following table

```
SET flatten_nested = 0;
CREATE TABLE test.hm
(
    customDimensions Array(Nested(index Nullable(Int64), value Nullable(String)))
)
    engine = Memory;
```

I am trying to insert into it with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test.hm FORMAT JSONEachRow {"customDimensions": [{"index": 1, "value": 2}]}
```

But it fails with

> Code: 130, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Array does not start with '[' character: (while reading the value of key customDimensions): (at row 1) (version 21.8.4.51 (official build))

How to fix it and insert `JSON` into `flatten_nested = 0` having multi lvl nested hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need `Array(Nested` because it's two-dimensional array.

you can use select to get understanding what JSONEachRow CH expectes

```sql
insert into test.hm values([[(1,'test1'), (2,'test2')]]);

select * from test.hm format JSONEachRow;
{"customDimensions":[[["1","test1"],["2","test2"]]]}
```

I guess you really need `Array(Tuple(index Nullable(Int64), value Nullable(String)))`

And you can use JSONExtract

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/altinity-kb-jsonasstring-and-mat.-view-as-json-parser/

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/jsonextract-to-parse-many-attributes-at-a-time/

Or https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/working-with-json/json-semi-structured/#json-object-type

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to make a conversion of the `RECORD` format in the Bigquery. And I thought that it is `Nested` in ch